# Edit labels in Trello

Tags: trello, trello-labels

It seems it's possible to change label's name, but I can't figure out how.

I found the label list in the board preferences, but the names aren't editable, they turn from grey to black when my mouse comes over, but that's all.

How can I change those labels' names?

Comment: Oh, and clicking the name doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you don't have the permission to change them.

Try to take a look at the ownership of the board, you should be a co-owner or the creator to be able to have them changed.

Comment: You're right, I'm not the owner of the board.
Thanks

Comment: When https://trello.com/card/board/let-any-board-member-edit-label-names/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4ed662e51ca2e7c80401c607 goes live, all board members will be able to edit board labels